# How to prevent broken dependencies on own packages?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, packaging

Two nights ago I compiled Calamares. The next morning, when trying to run it, I got:

> /usr/bin/calamares: error while loading shared libraries:
> libkpmcore.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory

I see that my distro, Manjaro, has updated kpmcore to have libkpmcore.so.12.

And here's my newbie question: what's the best chance I have to prevent this on my own Calamares package?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is `calamares` or `libkpmcore`. But the problem appears because of trying to resolve a non existance library.

Unix library naming usually follows the convention `lib{name}.so[.major[.minor[.patch]]]` (enclosed in `[]` means optional).

The problem with this naming scheme is that if you link to `lib{name}.so.0.1.0` for example, then update the library to `0.1.1`, this file no longer exists as it got replaced with `lib{name}.so.0.1.1`.

To workaround this, libraries have symlinks that point to the actual shared library

```
lib{name}.so.0.1 -> lib{name}.so.0.1.0
```

So when the library gets updated to `0.1.1`, programs using the previous version continue to work as the symlink still exists but point to the new version

```
lib{name}.so.0.1 -> lib{name}.so.0.1.1
```

In your case, you should link to the symlink, not the library.

Comment: I think that won't work, as the name shows ABI compatibility. Hence the new soname won't be compatible.